# Excel VBA looping issue (400000 rows)

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to loop through a worksheet that has over 400,000 rows. What I've done so far is as follows:

```
Sub FBR()

    Dim i As Range
        For Each i In Range("L2:L4000000")

            i.Value = "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-10],Sheet2!C[-11]:C[-9],2,FALSE)),,VLOOKUP(RC[-10],Sheet2!C[-11]:C[-9],2,FALSE))"

            i.Offset(, 1).Value = "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-11],Sheet2!C[-12]:C[-10],3,FALSE)),,VLOOKUP(RC[-11],Sheet2!C[-12]:C[-10],3,FALSE))"

                If i.Value = "RMF" Then
                    i.Offset(, 2).Value = "=ROUND(RC[-4]*RC[-3]*RC[-1]/365,2)"

                ElseIf i.Value = "AUM" Then
                    i.Offset(, 2).Value = "=ROUND(RC[-4]*RC[-1]/3650000,2)"


                End If

        Next i
End Sub
```

However I am unable to run this macro (I think due to an issue with the number of rows). Can anyone please suggest how I could resolve this issue. Thank you very much.

Comment: what is the concrete error message you get?

Comment: according to https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3 excel has a maximum of slightly more than 1 Mio rows

Comment: There is no concrete error message, instead the whole excel file stops working.

Comment: as I said before Excel has only ~ 1 Million rows. But your range is set to 4 Million.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems likely that Excel freezes because of performance issues, while trying to loop over the range you have specified. I would advice that instead of looping over the range you insert formula into the entire thing at once:

```
Range("L2:L400000").FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-10],Sheet1!C[-11]:C[-9],2,FALSE),"""")"
```

and:

```
Range("M2:M400000").FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-11],Sheet2!C[-12]:C[-10],3,FALSE),"""")"
```

Note that I also improved the formulas using [`IFERROR`](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/IFERROR-function-c526fd07-caeb-47b8-8bb6-63f3e417f611), as suggested by Jeeped in the comments.

You are still doing a large amount of fairly complicated calculations, so I would still expect some trouble, especially if you are not using a powerful computer.

To insert the last formula you want into column N, a loop may be the best solution, but to improve running speed of the macro, I would at the very least suggest that you put an `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` at the beginning of your macro and an `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` at the end to turn it back on. For further information on how to optimize running speed of your macro, you could have a look at e.g. [this blog post](https://blogs.office.com/2009/03/12/excel-vba-performance-coding-best-practices/).

Comment: Additionally, each formula could be evaluated twice if an `#N/A` is not encountered. Switch the formulas to use the [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5).

Comment: @Jeeped Thanks for the tip - I didn't really look too closely at the formulas themselves, as I suspect that the OP will end up with a really laggy workbook, even if the macro works (even with improved formulas).

Comment: @wontonwiz If this solved the problem for you, you can mark it as an answer to your question by using the checkmark at the top left of the question (under the arrows for voting).

Answer (score 0):

your range is set to 4 Million not 400.000

```
Sub FBR()

    Dim i As Range
        For Each i In Range("L2:L400000")

            i.Value = "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-10],Sheet2!C[-11]:C[-9],2,FALSE)),,VLOOKUP(RC[-10],Sheet2!C[-11]:C[-9],2,FALSE))"

            i.Offset(, 1).Value = "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-11],Sheet2!C[-12]:C[-10],3,FALSE)),,VLOOKUP(RC[-11],Sheet2!C[-12]:C[-10],3,FALSE))"

                If i.Value = "RMF" Then
                    i.Offset(, 2).Value = "=ROUND(RC[-4]*RC[-3]*RC[-1]/365,2)"

                ElseIf i.Value = "AUM" Then
                    i.Offset(, 2).Value = "=ROUND(RC[-4]*RC[-1]/3650000,2)"


                End If

        Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I have changed the range to ("L2:L400000"). Excel still freezes as I run the macro. Sorry for the inconvenience and your help is much appreciated.

Comment: are you sure to write the Formula in each cell?? 400K for 3 columns are 1,2 mil cells to write, and If you have the autosave mode, or every time you open the file all cells will be re-calculated.

Comment: @Fabrizio Yeah, I agree with you that it is most likely a performance issue, have a look at my answer to see how some of those issues may be somewhat remedied.

Comment: @eirikdaude ciao, I saw your answer. I asked if is necessary to write the formula into all cells, because if is possible write directly the result, is possible to use one array and play the code at least 30 times faster - without the problem of recalculations